# Moving and Consolidating Folders in AppleScript

Tags: macos, vba, applescript, taxonomy, finder

I have a folder called "Directory" with about 1000 subfolders. Each subfolder ("Student") contains one or more subfolders, which has one or more files. Is it possible to write a script that:

- Detects whether the subfolder has one or more than one subfolder
- If "Student" has ONLY one subfolder, move it into a new folder called "Bad" in the parent directory
- If "Student" has MORE THAN ONE subfolder, move it into a new folder called "Good" in the parent directory

Obviously, as a result, I need two folders in the "Directory" folder: one called "Bad", which contains all the folders containing one folder, and one called "Good", which contains all the folders containing more than one folder. In other words, I want the taxonomy to go from:

```
/Directory/Billy/Grades
/Directory/Billy/Student_Info
/Directory/Bob/Grades
/Directory/Bob/Student_Info  
/Directory/Joe/Student_Info
/Directory/George/Grades
```

To:

```
/Directory/Good/Billy/Grades
/Directory/Good/Billy/Student_Info
/Directory/Good/Bob/Grades
/Directory/Good/Bob/Student_Info
/Directory/Bad/Joe/Student_Info
/Directory/Bad/George/Grades
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this ago, it uses a few core Finder and AppleScripting ideas you can use in the future.

Please make a backup of your data first, just in case.

```
tell application "Finder"
    -- Define the full path to your data
    set student_data_folder to folder POSIX file "/Users/Foo/Desktop/bar/students/data"

    -- Get the student folders, ignoring good & bad incase they have already been created
    set all_student_folders to every folder of student_data_folder whose name is not in {"Good", "Bad"}

    --Create the good & bad folders if they don't exist
    set good_folder to my checkFolderExists("Good", student_data_folder)
    set bad_folder to my checkFolderExists("Bad", student_data_folder)

    -- Now loop through all student folders doing the sort based on how many subfolders they have
    repeat with student_folder in all_student_folders
        if (get the (count of folders in student_folder) > 1) then
            -- Its good
            move student_folder to good_folder
        else
            -- It's bad
            move student_folder to bad_folder
        end if
    end repeat

end tell

on checkFolderExists(fname, host_folder)
    tell application "Finder"
        if not (exists folder fname of host_folder) then
            return make new folder at host_folder with properties {name:fname}
        else
            return folder fname of host_folder
        end if
    end tell
end checkFolderExists
```

HTH

Comment: Why use POSIX instead of AS Aliases?

Comment: @Josh, just because the question used POSIX and i wanted to go with what the asker already knew. Also HFS paths are a bit old school and less legible to a wider xplat and web aware user base.

Comment: I actually had no idea Applescript would accept POSIX for it's own functions. I've always been converting everything to POSIX, changing it as needed, and then going back to HFS for when I need to use it. Nice to know all that trouble was for nothing. +1 for the good answer

Comment: Also, I'm grateful that you used POSIX. I would have been pretty confused otherwise.